# Change allowed mail size quota

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, procmail

The email server on my ubuntu machine can only receive mails up to 10 megabytes in size.
I would like to change that value, but I'm so blind I can't figure out where to change it.

```
Could not be delivered because of

Server refused mail at MAIL FROM - 552 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed limit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Postfix

- add "message_size_limit = 102400000" in "/etc/postfix/main.cf"
- reload postfix: sudo postfix reload
- check message_size_limit

Example(100Mb):

```
$ sudo postconf message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 102400000
```

This is documented on the [Postfix site](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html):

> **message_size_limit (default: 10240000)**
>
> The maximal size in bytes of a message, including envelope information.
>
> Note: be careful when making changes. Excessively small values will result in the loss of non-delivery notifications, when a bounce message size exceeds the local or remote MTA's message size limit.

Answer (score 1):

Open  /etc/postfix/main.cf find message_size_limit and change it from 10240000 (10mb) to e.g. 
20480000

Answer (score 0):

Get:

```
postconf -n | grep message_size_limit

10240000
```

Set:

```
sudo postconf -e 'message_size_limit = 31457280'
```

Get (to see if it worked):

```
postconf -n | grep message_size_limit

31457280
```